# Reverse spinning wind generator

Tags: electromagnetism

I broke a blade on my wind generator.  The maker says they have new blades that rotate the opposite direction now.  At first that sounds like a no-go, but then after thinking about it, the wires are all the same (no ABC, connect any to any on the controller) so the controller shouldn't care.  The only real question is, will it cause problems with the generator itself if it spins backwards from how it was designed?  And, would it actually create electricity?

Note: I doubt the reps at the company would even know the correct answer and if they did, I doubt they would say anything other than 'you can't do that'.  I highly suspect they reversed it just to make us buy new ones when a blade breaks.

Answer (score 1):

This is determined by the type of your generator. If it generates a 3-phase AC current, then reversing the rotating direction doesn't matter since all ABC wired symmetrically only with a phase difference. That is most likely you are using a ac generator. If your generator yields DC current, reversing the rotation direction will reverse the current direction on your asymmetric circuit where there may be a diode to prevent reversed rotations. In the end, you still need to consult the company for the parameters and model types of the generator. If they give you a wrong answer, they have to take charge for the aftermath. Hope this answered your question.

Comment: It is AC.  3 wires connecting to a rectifier in no order.  I believe some have to be connected in order but this controller says no order necessary.